# what does `ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec` do?

Tags: flutter

I see my flutter project generated a file `ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec`, what does this file used for ?

1. if it's related to generated `Flutter.framework` ?
2. Should I include it in our source manage repo ?
3. Can I change it so that, for example, with `s.ios.deployment_target='11.0'`, `Flutter.framework` will build with target `iOS 11`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained here:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Podspec file "describes a version of Pod library." It includes details about where the source should be fetched from, what files to use, the build settings to apply, and other general metadata such as its name, version, and description.

1. It is related, the framework is fetched according to this file.
2. No. This file is excluded by default in `ios/.gitignore`
3. The file is generated, you should never modify it. You can change deployment target in `ios/Podfile`